# Javascript "for of" fails in IE 11

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11

I have the following bit of code to select and remove a d3.js node.

```
 if (d.children) {
        for (var child of d.children) {
            if (child == node) {
                d.children = _.without(d.children, child);
                update(root);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

This works fine in Chrome and Edge, but fails in IE-11 with missing ;. It appears to be a problem with using 'of' to loop. Has anyone else run across this issue with IE before and if so how did you resolve it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of note the browser compatibility

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `for..in`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is an ES2015 (also know as ES6) feature and only supported in modern browsers. Generally you would only use this construct together with a transpiler like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) in order to support older browsers.

You can see the compatibility table for the `for...of` statement here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: The above link doesn't (currently) show IE11 support — nothing before Edge.

Comment: @kevnk any IE version before MS Edge does not support _for...of_ statement (as it belongs to ES6).